# Injecting javascript variable before content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using my background script background.js, I need to inject a dynamic variable as a content script before injecting another file inject.js also as a content script. Inject.js will need to have access to this variable and run it's code BEFORE any scripts on the page run. I am having difficulties accessing the dynamic variable from the inject.js content script.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Shape Shifter",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Anti browser fingerprinting web extension. Generates randomised values for HTTP request headers, javascript property values and javascript method return types.",
"manifest_version": 2,
"icons": {
    "32": "icons/person-32.png",
    "48": "icons/person-48.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["js/ua.js", "js/words.js", "js/lib/seedrandom.min.js", "js/random.js", "js/background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Shape Shifter",
    "default_icon": "icons/person-32.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["js/inject.js"] 
  }
],
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/ua.js",
    "js/words.js",
    "js/lib/seedrandom.min.js",
    "js/random.js",
    "js/api/document.js",
    "js/api/navigator.js",
    "js/api/canvas.js",
    "js/api/history.js",
    "js/api/battery.js",
    "js/api/audio.js",
    "js/api/element.js"
]
```

}

background.js

```
"use strict";

console.log("Background Script Running ...");

function getSeed(origin) {
    // Get a Storage object
    var storage = window.localStorage;

    // Do we already have a seed in storage for this origin or not?
    var seed = storage.getItem(origin);

    if (seed === null) {
        // Initialise a 32 byte buffer
        seed = new Uint8Array(32);

        // Fill it with cryptographically random values
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(seed);

        // Save it to storage
        storage.setItem(origin, seed);
    }

    return seed;
}

// Methods to get HTTP headers
function getAcceptHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getAcceptCharsetHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getAcceptEncodingHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getAcceptLanguageHeader() {
    // NOTE: TOR Browser uses American English
    return "en-US,en;q=0.5";
}
function getAuthorizationHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getExpectHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getFromHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getHostHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getIfMatchHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getIfModifiedSinceHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getIfNoneMatchHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getIfRangeHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getIfUnmodifiedSinceHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getMaxForwardsHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getProxyAuthorizationHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getRangeHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getRefererHeader() {
    // NOTE: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer
    // NOTE: The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark).
    // NOTE: Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page.

    // NOTE: Make websites think we always go to them directly rather than being referred.
    return "";
}
function getTEHeader(seed) {
    return "NotYetImplemented";
}
function getUserAgentHeader(seed) {
    Math.seedrandom(seed);

    return userAgents[randomNumber(0, userAgents.length)];
}

function rewriteHttpHeaders(e) {
    // Create URL object from url string
    var serverUrl = new URL(e.url);

    console.log(e);

    // Get the origin (hostname)
    var origin = serverUrl.hostname;

    var seed = getSeed(origin);

    console.log("Background - Seed for origin " + origin + ": " + seed);

    for (var header of e.requestHeaders) {
        if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "accept") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "accept-charset") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "accept-encoding") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "accept-language") {
            header.value = getAcceptLanguageHeader();
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "authorization") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "expect") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "from") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "host") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "if-match") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "if-modified-since") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "if-none-match") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "if-range") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "if-unmodified-since") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "max-forwards") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "proxy-authorization") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "range") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "referer") {
            header.value = getRefererHeader();
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "te") {
        }
        else if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "user-agent") {
            header.value = getUserAgentHeader(seed);
        }
    }

    return {requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders};
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(rewriteHttpHeaders, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details) {
    // Create URL object from url string
    var serverUrl = new URL(details.url);

    // Get the origin (hostname)
    var origin = serverUrl.hostname;

    var seed = "Some dynamic value";

    console.log("Injecting Value");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {code: "var seed = '" + seed + "';console.log(seed);", runAt: "document_start"}, function() {
        console.log("Value Injected");
    });
});
```

inject.js

```
(function() {
  function inject(filePath) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filePath);
    script.onload = function() {
      this.remove();
    };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
  }

  function injectText(text) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = text;
    script.onload = function() {
      this.remove();
    };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
  }

  console.log("CONTENT SCRIPT RUNNING");

  console.log(seed); // SEED IS NOT DEFINED HERE ???

  injectText("var seed = 'hello';");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Seed ...");
  inject("js/ua.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected UA ...");
  inject("js/words.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Words ...");
  inject("js/lib/seedrandom.min.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Seed Random ...");
  inject("js/random.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Random ...");
  inject("js/api/document.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Document API ...");
  inject("js/api/navigator.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Navigator API ...");
  inject("js/api/canvas.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Canvas API ...");
  inject("js/api/history.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected History API ...");
  inject("js/api/battery.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Battery API ...");
  inject("js/api/audio.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Audio API ...");
  inject("js/api/element.js");
  console.log("[INFO] Injected Element API ...");
})();
```

I get the error when trying to log the seed to the console:

```
inject.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: seed is not defined
    at inject.js:26
    at inject.js:52
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you expect `seed` to be defined when you log it on that line?

Comment: Related: [Google chrome extension: how to inject script immediately after page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42151342)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This is going to be very tricky.

Let's look at your requirements.

> Inject.js will need to have access to this variable and run it's code BEFORE any scripts on the page run.

That's not how your code currently works. Your `inject.js` is executed at `document_end` - which happens *after* the whole DOM tree is parsed, which means after *all* page scripts have run (barring asynchronous parts and `async` script loading).

Chrome has a solution to that - you can set your execution to `document_start`. Then your code will truly run *before everything else*, while DOM is still not parsed (so `document` is essentially empty). With what your code does, it should not create problems (it only relies on `document.documentElement`, which will exist).

Problem is, all your code has to be *synchronous* to still enjoy "runs before everything else" property. Chrome will pause DOM parsing as long as the synchronous part of your code runs, but then all bets are off as it merrily continues to parse (and run code from) the document.

This, for example, disqualifies `chrome.storage` and Messaging as access to that is necessarily asynchronous.

> I need to inject a dynamic variable [on a page load]

Meaning that you cannot store this in advance in some synchronously-available storage (e.g. in `localStorage` or cookies of the website), which would be problematic anyway considering you don't know domains in advance.

*Note, for your code in particular, this may not be that much of a factor; your "dynamic" value is in fact fixed per domain. You still don't know in advance which domain will be visited, but you can at least guarantee that on a second load it will be there.*

> Using my background script background.js, I need to inject a dynamic variable as a content script **before injecting another file** [that still needs to run before everything else on the page]

*That's* the tricky part. **In fact, as stated, it's simply impossible.** You're trying to catch, from the background, the exact moment between the navigation being committed, so that Chrome switched the page to the new domain, and the execution of your `document_start` script.

There is no detectable gap there, and no way to tell Chrome to wait. It's a race condition you have no hopes to resolve.

You're trying to use `webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` - before even the navigation is committed. So your `injectScript` probably goes to the previous page even, rendering it useless. If you try some other event, e.g . `onCommitted`, there's still no telling as to when exactly `injectScript` will be treated. Likely *after* your script.

### So, how to work around all this?

Fortunately, there is some *synchronous* storage that's available to the content script that you can push some information to *right before* the earliest of scripts executes.

**Cookies.**

However, using the `chrome.cookies` API won't help. You need to actively inject the cookie value into the request on `webRequest.onHeadersReceived`.

You have to have the value ready *synchronously* to process it with a blocking handler to `onHeadersReceived`, but then you can simply add one `Set-Cookie` header and have it immediately available in `document.cookies` in your `inject.js`.

- background.js

  ```js
  function addSeedCookie(details) {
    seed = SomethingSynchronous();
    details.responseHeaders.push({
      name: "Set-Cookie",
      value: `seed_goes_here=${seed};`
    });
    return {
      responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
    };
  }

  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    addSeedCookie, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, [
      "blocking",
      "responseHeaders",
      // Chrome 72+ requires 'extraHeaders' to handle Set-Cookie header
      chrome.webRequest.OnHeadersReceivedOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS,
    ].filter(Boolean)
  );
  ```
- inject.js

  ```js
  function getCookie(cookie) { // https://stackoverflow.com/a/19971550/934239
    return document.cookie.split(';').reduce(function(prev, c) {
      var arr = c.split('=');
      return (arr[0].trim() === cookie) ? arr[1] : prev;
    }, undefined);
  }

  var seed = getCookie("seed_goes_here");
  ```

**If an *asynchronous* function** is needed to produce the data, prepare the data before the request is sent in onBeforeRequest event, then use it in onHeadersReceived listener.

```js
const preparedSeed = {};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  details => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('seed', data => {
      preparedSeed[details.requestId] = data.seed;
    });
  }, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>'],
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
  });
```

*Note: the above code is untested and only serves to illustrate the idea.*

Comment: Looks like it was a tricky problem. I ended up finding a different solution altogether to my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow how the heck did you come up with this Xan? Genius.

Comment: I do love the concept, but a.) we only get a max of 4 KBs of data with cookies, and b.) websites could detect this unless very carefully built.  Maybe this might suffice for the OP, but I may have MBs in my case.  Is there really no other way? :-(