# Chrome extension inject script with dynamic value into page with strict CSP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am creating a privacy extension that runs a content script on document_start.

The content script needs to inject a script with a dynamic value for each different origin e.g. google.com, twitter.com etc etc.

This is my content script:

```
console.log("Content Script Running ...");
console.log("Window origin: " + window.location.href);

function inject(filePath) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filePath);
  script.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
  };
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

function injectText(text) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = text;
  script.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
  };
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

function getSeed(origin) {
    // Get a Storage object
    var storage = window.sessionStorage;

    // Do we already have a seed in storage for this origin or not?
    var seed = storage.getItem(origin);

    if (seed === null) {
        // Initialise a 32 byte buffer
        seed = new Uint8Array(32);

        // Fill it with cryptographically random values
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(seed);

        // Save it to storage
        storage.setItem(origin, seed);
    }

    return seed;
}

var origin = window.location.hostname;

var seed = getSeed(origin);

injectText("var seed = '" + seed + "';");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Seed ...");

inject("js/lib/seedrandom.min.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Seed Random ...");

inject("js/random.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Random ...");

inject("js/api/document.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Document API ...");

inject("js/api/navigator.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Navigator API ...");

inject("js/api/canvas.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Canvas API ...");

inject("js/api/history.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected History API ...");

inject("js/api/battery.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Battery API ...");

inject("js/api/audio.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Audio API ...");

inject("js/api/element.js");
console.log("[INFO] Injected Element API ...");
```

When trying to run this extension on a website with a strict CSP e.g. github.com, my script with a dynamic seed value is blocked and my other scripts which depend on that value end up referencing an undefined value. Any ideas how I can get around this.

The scripts loaded using the src attribute are ok since they are in a .js file and are loaded from the extension however that one script that has a dynamic value aka var seed = ... is blocked because it is injected using the textContent attribute.

I need to have this code run syncronously and before any other script on the page run hence why i have the content script run on document_start.

Any ideas?

Comment: Modify CSP header via chrome.webRequest API.

Comment: OK. Wouldn't this create a possible security issue for the site? Or is there a way to do this safely? I don't want my addon to be known as "The addon that messes with websites CSP". Maybe I'm over reacting.

Comment: Calculate sha256 of your injected code (e.g. via built-in crypto API) and use it in your modified CSP.

Comment: I can't. The code changes each time for each page. E.g. for google.com it would be "var seed = 'value0';" then for another site it could be 'var seed = "value1";' I could maybe use the nonce feature? and give my inline script a nonce perhaps?

Comment: If you can generate that code at the time webRequest listener runs, you certainly can calculate sha256 right away.

Comment: That code is generated in the content script not the background script where the webRequest code is (I haven't posted the background script). I could use chrome.tabs.executeScript() in background page to inject content script with dynamic value then use that value and inject it again into the page however I have had timing issues with executeScript() manifest document_start is more reliable. Anyway thanks for your help you have given me some good ideas.

Comment: You can do synchronous communication from the content script to the background page via sync XHR (it'll display a deprecation warning in the console) which is intercepted with webRequest. The problem we'll be the timing, though: the content script runs after webRequest.onHeadersReceived. I guess you'll have to rework your extension to generate the injected code in bg. See also: [sync communication from bg to content script via cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105934) (in case of long strings use blob urls i.e. createObjectURL in bg and sync XHR in the content script)

Comment: Why do you need to transfer this data inserted as a `<script>`? it sounds like it's just data. You could just transfer it as the `detail` of a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) sent from your content script to your inserted page script. Unless it's data which isn't JSON-ifiable, you should be able to handle it that way. You could also do it with `window.postMessage()`, but, in my experience, it's more likely to conflict with in-page use of the `message` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The main issue I was having was trying to inject an inline text script which had the following content:

```
var seed = $(value that changes depending on the page)
```

This gets blocked by certain websites such as twitter.com and github.com which have restrictive content security policies.

My solution was to do the following in my content script:

```
var filePath = // Get filepath to script
var seed = // Get seed value in content script

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("data-seed", seed);
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filePath);
script.onload = function() {
  this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

This will create a script in the page like so

```
<script data-seed="$(DATA-SEED-VALUE)" src="$(SRC-VALUE)"></script>
```

Then from within this script which is now running as a page script (in the content of the web page):

```
var seed = document.currentScript.getAttribute("data-seed");
```

Which gets the seed. This solution is much neater, easier and doesn't require altering CSP which could create security issues for the site you are interacting with.