# How to get extension state (enabled/disabled) synchronously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

From content.js I need to detect the extension state (enabled/disabled). Currently I'm using `chrome.storage.sync.set` in background.js to set the state, and `chrome.storage.sync.get` in content.js to get the state. However this is running asynchronously, which is not what I want. Is there a way to get the extension state synchronously (i.e. the page loading will freeze until I get the current state)?

Comment: No. The only workaround in Chrome is [webRequest + cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105934/).