# How to identify a new tab is opened by user manually in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating new tab in chrome extension using following code;

```
var url="https://www.test.com";
chrome.tabs.create({url:url, active: false}, 
 function(tab)
 {      
 }
 );
```

How to identify, is the newly opened tab is created by my extension, or
user has manually opened the url in a new tab?

I need to know it within content script. I have already some code in content script. I'm looking for a solution which not uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage();

But not knowing how to identify the caller before fully loading the page.

Can we pass an parameter when creating a new tab?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Injecting javascript variable before content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105934)

Answer (score 1):

I found out through using `chrome.tabs.onCreated` that when a user opens a new tab themselves the tab properties would have `status` as `loading`, `url` as `chrome://newtab`.

Try this:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(t){
    if(t.status === 'loading' && t.url === 'chrome://newtab'){}
});
```