# Improve page load latency in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a google chrome extension that looks at a webpage, does some calculations based on features of the page, and then loads an iFrame to display the results. Currently, I am working on trying to create a more accessible version for visually-impared users. I have an option in my options page to allow users to click if they want to use the visually accessible option, and then that information is stored as a boolean in browser storage. The issue is, I have to check for that boolean in storage every single time I load the iFrame (which is every time the page switches or refreshes), and it adds roughly **500ms** of latency to the iFrame load.

I have tried using both chrome.storage.sync, and localStorage (from background, with message passing to my content script) to see if the synchronous version would be a bit faster, but they both add roughly 500ms to the running of my content script. Right now I have two different html files, the standard one and the visually accessible one, and the content script chooses which to load based on retrieving the accessibility boolean from storage. If there is a faster way to just programmatically switch the css that the standard html file loads, I could do that as well. The thing is, any way I figure it, I just can't seem to think of a way to avoid having to retrieve the boolean from storage every single time the iFrame loads.

I suppose I'm wondering if there is some other way around this, like if I could somehow direct the extension to just automatically use a certain version of the html based on which option the user selects when they install the extension. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the function in question (from content script):

```
function insertFrame(){
var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({contentScriptQuery: "accessible?"}, function(response){
        var accessible = response;
        if(accessible === "true"){
            //load the accessible frame
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = "myFrame";
            iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('accessible.html');
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }else{
            //load the regular frame
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = "myFrame";
            iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html');
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        console.log("Time to run content script:", Date.now() - timer);
    });   
}   
    //for testing purposes
//        var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
//        if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
//            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
//            iframe.id = "myFrame";
//            iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html');
//            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
//        }   
//        console.log("Time to run content script:", Date.now() - startTime);
}
```

And in my background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.contentScriptQuery === 'accessible?'){
        var a = localStorage.getItem('accessible');
        sendResponse(a);
    }
    return true; //with or without this line, timing is the same
});
```

I've been testing the content script just by commenting out each half (with and without reading from storage). You can see the line where I am logging how many milliseconds have elapsed since the content script started running. I have also verified this latency by testing load times in the network panel of dev tools. I get an average of 6.33s for load time without reading storage, and 6.72s with reading storage, which confirms the timing discrepancy I am logging in my content script. The only thing I am changing between tests are commenting out the half of the function so that I can test the other half.

Comment: Reading the storage takes just a few milliseconds, 100 times less than what you observe, so the problem is caused by something else for which you need to show [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah I read storage in other places in much less time, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I added the problematic code in the above question, along with a bit of an explanation of how I'm testing it.

Comment: Nothing obvious in the code so it must be something else again. For example, loading/running page's own scripts can cause it because the response will be processed only afterwards. Use devtools' `Performance` tab to profile the page load process. See also [Injecting javascript variable before content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105934)