# Set the localStorage of a new chrome created tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, listener, content-script

So I'm creating a new tab in my background.js (Web extension) and I'm trying to set its localsotrage from content script after creating it.
this is my background.js script :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {  
  if (message.from == "content") {
      chrome.tabs.create({
      url:message.url,
      active:true
      },function(tab){      
      sendResponse({access: "yes"});
      console.log("callback function");
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { message: 'background' });      
      });
  }
});
```

the tab is creating, and this is my content script function to listen to my background script after creating the new tab :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {  
    console.log('msg recu');
    if (message.msg == 'background') {    
    localStorage.setItem("test","test");
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately, the localstorage is not setting. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: See my comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67183872/set-localstorage-after-creating-a-new-tab).

Comment: @wOxxOm how can I reverse the direction of messaging and ask for the data from my content script?

Comment: Currently your background script initiates messaging so reversing means the content script will initiate it (sendMessage) while the background script will listen (onMessage) and respond (sendResponse).

Comment: @wOxxOm I did do it thank you, but now it creates a new tab but it sets the local storage in the old one.

Comment: It means your code is wrong.

Comment: @wOxxOm I setted an interval after the response and now it's working fine.