# How does "instant inject" in tampermonkey work?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

In tampermonkey, advanced settings, you can find a setting called "Inject mode" at the "Expirimental" tab. Here, you can select a mode called "Instant".

I was wondering, what does it do different? How does it work? Is it simular to ViolentMonkeys injection methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the source code in other extensions like Stylus or Violentmonkey (beta) that recently added the same feature:

1. The background script makes a `Blob` in the background script with the data, gets its URL via `URL.createObjectURL`, puts it into a `Set-Cookie` header via chrome.webRequest API.
2. The content script reads the URL from `document.cookie` and uses it in a synchronous XMLHttpRequest to get the original data synchronously.

This trick is based on an [answer by Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105934).

Comment: For reference, the source code of ViolentMonkey's implementation is available here: https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey/pull/1100